Reading CAN(Controller Area Network) data in flutter app
I am using Debix IMX8 SBC with Android 11 installed for CAN communication. As per Debix document, I implemented CAN commands in terminal and successfully getting data in terminal.But not able to understand how to read same incoming data through flutter application.
I found this library linux_can and tried to use it.But application is throwing error "Failed to load dynamic library 'libc.so.6'".
Is there any library availble for reading incoming CAN data in flutter application? If not how do I read CAN data in application?
Please help, Thank you.
